# Doctrine read connection with database based on local environment variables

Tags: symfony, doctrine, environment-variables

I have a new project in Symfony 4 framework. 
In this project I have few files with  environment variables: .env, .env.dev, .env.local, .env.rc

In my env.local I'm trying to connect with database locally. In .env.local I have enviroment variable:

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:@127.0.0.1:3306/ecerti"
```

The problem is Symfony reads DATABASE_URL from .env.dev instead of .env.local when I'm running command:

```
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
```

What should I do in order to reading environment variables from .env.local locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `.env.dev.local` filename in this case.

Please refer [Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#managing-multiple-env-files) for list of possible `.env` files and their priorities.